# Accuracy stuck training on binary matrix input in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I have a set of about 1500 features and 300 classes. Each input object can be described by a certain number of features from this set of 1500 and is classified as one of those 300 classes. 
Input objects are 'vectorized' or 'embedded' based on the presence of a feature. For example, one object has 25 features and therefore expressed as a vector with 25 1's and 1475 0's. Class labels are one-hot encoded. 
The input dataset has around 10k rows, so the X_train set shape is (10000,1500) and Y_train is (10000, 325) so the matrices are quite sparse.
I am trying to build a multiclass classifier in Keras. 
Here is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3000, input_dim=1500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(2500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(2000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(1500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(400, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(300, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy',metrics.top_k_categorical_accuracy])
```

The issue is that accuracy never gets higher than 0.4 even after 100-200-300 epochs. Tried varying the number of hidden layers and neurons, and turning off dropout and any regularization, but the result is still the same.

```
Epoch 4/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 4.0560 - acc: 0.2440 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.3423 - val_loss: 3.6102 - val_acc: 0.3235 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.3987
Epoch 5/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.5148 - acc: 0.3233 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4218 - val_loss: 3.2821 - val_acc: 0.4015 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4377
Epoch 6/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.3581 - acc: 0.3585 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4401 - val_loss: 3.2520 - val_acc: 0.4053 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4339
Epoch 7/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.2331 - acc: 0.3898 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4460 - val_loss: 3.1321 - val_acc: 0.4196 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4358
Epoch 8/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.1762 - acc: 0.4003 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4477 - val_loss: 3.1258 - val_acc: 0.4215 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4377
Epoch 9/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.1389 - acc: 0.4086 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4513 - val_loss: 3.0792 - val_acc: 0.4272 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4405
Epoch 10/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0873 - acc: 0.4224 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4505 - val_loss: 3.0815 - val_acc: 0.4263 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4396
Epoch 11/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0869 - acc: 0.4242 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4539 - val_loss: 3.1044 - val_acc: 0.4272 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4377
Epoch 12/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 28s - loss: 3.0760 - acc: 0.4260 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4528 - val_loss: 3.0833 - val_acc: 0.4263 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4405
Epoch 13/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0815 - acc: 0.4236 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4528 - val_loss: 3.0685 - val_acc: 0.4282 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4396
Epoch 14/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0963 - acc: 0.4207 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4517 - val_loss: 3.1324 - val_acc: 0.4196 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4377
Epoch 15/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0927 - acc: 0.4197 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4530 - val_loss: 3.0870 - val_acc: 0.4272 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4396
Epoch 16/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0795 - acc: 0.4257 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4530 - val_loss: 3.0834 - val_acc: 0.4301 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4415
Epoch 17/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0657 - acc: 0.4266 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4533 - val_loss: 3.1244 - val_acc: 0.4253 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4405
Epoch 18/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0784 - acc: 0.4262 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4551 - val_loss: 3.0882 - val_acc: 0.4272 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4443
Epoch 19/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0540 - acc: 0.4303 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4525 - val_loss: 3.0817 - val_acc: 0.4282 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4405
Epoch 20/300
9450/9450 [==============================] - 27s - loss: 3.0815 - acc: 0.4255 - top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4516 - val_loss: 3.0910 - val_acc: 0.4244 - val_top_k_categorical_accuracy: 0.4405
```

Any ideas how to increase the accuracy or maybe smth is wrong with the input data?

Comment: You have a ton of classes, and not alot of data, so that could be an issue here. If your data was uniformly divided, you would have around 30 samples per class. Thats not a lot really. And you have 7 hidden layer, Just imagine how hard it would be to tain that many neurons, with such a small sample size.

Comment: Also you may want to use a convolution or an LSTM layer, which are used to learn patterns within a sequence

Comment: I would try with 2 or 3 layers, with a fewer units `256, 128, 64` maybe. BatchNormalization layers. Leaky relu, or switch to convolutions. If you can, get more data.

Comment: @djk47463 Okay, if I use LSTM or convolutional layers how should I reshape the input then?

Comment: use a 1d convolution and reshape as X.reshape(-1,1500,1)